# Issues with setting up redis cluster via docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to configure the Redis cluster using the docker image `bitnami/redis-cluster`.

Following is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis-node-0:
    image: bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7
    volumes:
      - redis-node-data-0:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2

  redis-node-1:
    image: bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7
    volumes:
      - redis-node-data-1:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2

  redis-node-2:
    image: bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7
    volumes:
      - redis-node-data-2:/bitnami/redis/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis-node-0
      - redis-node-1
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2
      - REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=1
      - REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes

volumes:
  redis-node-data-0:
    driver: local
  redis-node-data-1:
    driver: local
  redis-node-data-2:
    driver: local
networks:
  default:
    name: local_network
```

Docker container's are perfectly running:
Output of `docker ps`:

| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bea9a7c52eba | bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7 | "/opt/bitnami/script…" | 12 minutes ago | 12 minutes ago | 0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp | local-redis-node-2-1 |
| 63c08f1330e0 | bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7 | "/opt/bitnami/script…" | 12 minutes ago | 12 minutes ago | 6379/tcp | local-redis-node-1-1 |
| e1b163d75254 | bitnami/redis-cluster:6.2.7 | "/opt/bitnami/script…" | 12 minutes ago | 12 minutes ago | 6379/tcp | local-redis-node-0-1 |

As I have set `local-redis-node-2-1` as `REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR`, now it is the incharge of initializing the cluster. Therefore, I am executing all below commands with this node.

Going inside container: `docker exec -it local-redis-node-2-1 redis-cli`

Then, trying to save data in redis `set a 1`, I am getting error: `(error) CLUSTERDOWN Hash slot not serve`

Output of `cluster slots`: `(empty array)`

I tried `docker exec -it local-redis-node-2-1 redis-cli --cluster fix localhost:6379`. But it is assigning `6379 slots out of 16383` to `local-redis-node-2-1` only, remaining slots are not getting assigned to other nodes. Below is the output of `cluster slots` after fixing via above command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster slots
1) 1) (integer) 0
   2) (integer) 16383
   3) 1) "172.18.0.9"
      2) (integer) 6379
      3) "819770cf8b39793517efa10b9751083c854e15d7"
```

I am doing something wrong. I would love to know the manual solution as well but more interested in knowing the solution to set cluster slots via docker-compose.

1. **Can someone help me in setting the cluster slots automatically via docker-compose.yml?**
2. **The read replicas will work or not with this docker-compose.yml or have I missed something?**
3. **Also, can someone confirm whether the cluster will work fine after resolving the cluster slots or not?**

Logs of `local-redis-node-2-1` below:

```
redis-cluster 00:47:45.70 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.73 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-cluster container
redis-cluster 00:47:45.76 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
redis-cluster 00:47:45.78 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
redis-cluster 00:47:45.80 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.83 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis-cluster 00:47:46.00 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
redis-cluster 00:47:46.05 INFO  ==> Initializing Redis
redis-cluster 00:47:46.29 INFO  ==> Setting Redis config file
Changing old IP 172.18.0.8 by the new one 172.18.0.8
Changing old IP 172.18.0.6 by the new one 172.18.0.6
Changing old IP 172.18.0.9 by the new one 172.18.0.9
redis-cluster 00:47:47.30 INFO  ==> ** Redis setup finished! **

1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.579 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.580 # Redis version=6.2.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.580 # Configuration loaded
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.584 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.588 * Node configuration loaded, I'm 819770cf8b39793517efa10b9751083c854e15d7
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.595 # A key '__redis__compare_helper' was added to Lua globals which is not on the globals allow list nor listed on the deny list.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.598 * Running mode=cluster, port=6379.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.599 # Server initialized
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.612 * Ready to accept connections
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:49.673 # Cluster state changed: ok
```

Logs of `local-redis-node-1-1` below:

```
redis-cluster 00:47:45.43 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.46 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-cluster container
redis-cluster 00:47:45.48 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
redis-cluster 00:47:45.51 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
redis-cluster 00:47:45.54 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.56 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis-cluster 00:47:45.73 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
redis-cluster 00:47:45.79 INFO  ==> Initializing Redis
redis-cluster 00:47:46.00 INFO  ==> Setting Redis config file
Changing old IP 172.18.0.8 by the new one 172.18.0.8
Changing old IP 172.18.0.6 by the new one 172.18.0.6
Changing old IP 172.18.0.9 by the new one 172.18.0.9
redis-cluster 00:47:47.10 INFO  ==> ** Redis setup finished! **

1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.387 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.388 # Redis version=6.2.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.388 # Configuration loaded
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.392 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.395 * Node configuration loaded, I'm 2ab0b8db952cc101f7873cdcf8cf691f8f6bae7b
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.403 # A key '__redis__compare_helper' was added to Lua globals which is not on the globals allow list nor listed on the deny list.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.406 * Running mode=cluster, port=6379.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.407 # Server initialized
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.418 * Ready to accept connections
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:56:02.716 # New configEpoch set to 1
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:56:41.943 # Cluster state changed: ok
```

Logs of `local-redis-node-0-1` below:

```
redis-cluster 00:47:45.43 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.46 Welcome to the Bitnami redis-cluster container
redis-cluster 00:47:45.49 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
redis-cluster 00:47:45.51 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
redis-cluster 00:47:45.54 
redis-cluster 00:47:45.56 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis-cluster 00:47:45.73 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
redis-cluster 00:47:45.79 INFO  ==> Initializing Redis
redis-cluster 00:47:46.00 INFO  ==> Setting Redis config file
Changing old IP 172.18.0.8 by the new one 172.18.0.8
Changing old IP 172.18.0.6 by the new one 172.18.0.6
Changing old IP 172.18.0.9 by the new one 172.18.0.9
redis-cluster 00:47:47.11 INFO  ==> ** Redis setup finished! **

1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.387 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.388 # Redis version=6.2.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.388 # Configuration loaded
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.391 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.395 * Node configuration loaded, I'm 5ffeca48faa750a5f47c76639598fdb9b7b8b720
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.402 # A key '__redis__compare_helper' was added to Lua globals which is not on the globals allow list nor listed on the deny list.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.405 * Running mode=cluster, port=6379.
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.405 # Server initialized
1:M 10 Dec 2022 00:47:47.415 * Ready to accept connections
```